# Having trouble with a windows service that pings ~200 addresses

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

Updated question for Ping Async:  [Large amount of pings in async task - getting Exception "An asynchronous call is already in progress."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149379/large-amount-of-pings-in-async-task-getting-exception-an-asynchronous-call-is)

I've got a Windows Service that grabs a list of hosts from a MySQL Database and reports back if the host was pingable.  This works great for small amounts of IP's, but I'm expecting about 200+ IP's at a time, and one or two hosts being down is causing a lot of lag.   My quick and dirty solution was opening the ping's in a thread, so that the loop can continue to run if one host is down or has a slow network... It works.. but not well.  I'm new at this, but I know enough to realize this can't be the best way to do it.  Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
try
        {
            MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand query = Connection.CreateCommand();
            query.CommandText = "SELECT obj_id AS id,ip FROM objects LIMIT 200";
            MySqlDataReader Nodes = query.ExecuteReader();

            // Record in log that a NEW iteration is starting - for tracking issues with pings
            Library.WriteErrorLog("######################## New Iteration ########################");

            int i = 1;
            while(Nodes.Read())
            {
                // Open a new thread for each ping.  There are over 2000 host objects in the database - if we do not open in seperate threads we will never finish
                // each thread will ping the hosts and results will be logged in log.txt and MySQL
                string  Host = (i == 5 ? "google.com" : Nodes["ip"].ToString());
                        Host = (i == 4 ? "lindevenv" : Host);
                int HostID      = int.Parse(Nodes["id"].ToString()); // Obj -> string -> int because super awesome .NET logic
                Thread thread = new Thread(() => UpdateStatus(Host, HostID, ConnectionString, i));
                thread.Start();
                i++;
            }

            Connection.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Error: " + ee.ToString());
        }
```

and...

```
// Called by the thread as the worker method inside CheckStatus Method below
    private void UpdateStatus(string Host, int HostID, string ConnectionString, int loopID)
    {
        try
        {
            Ping pinger = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send(Host, 3000);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Library.WriteErrorLog("(" + loopID + ") " + Host + " is UP!");
            }
            else
            {
                Library.WriteErrorLog("(" + loopID + ") " + Host + " is DOWN!");
                Library.ReportDown(HostID, ConnectionString);
            }
        }
        catch (PingException e)
        {
            // Do not throw exception - a pingexception is thrown when there is a timeout/dns/other issue - report as down
            Library.WriteErrorLog("(" + loopID + ") " + Host + " is DOWN!");
            Library.ReportDown(HostID, ConnectionString);
        }
    }
```

In addition to being extemely memory heavy, some information gets left out/duplicated between threads which makes it very unreliable.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use Ping.SendAsync instead of Ping.Send.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm having issues implementing Ping.SendAsync - question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149379/large-amount-of-pings-in-async-task-getting-exception-an-asynchronous-call-is