# Large amount of pings in async task - getting Exception "An asynchronous call is already in progress."

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, ping

I posted a previous question about this, I found a sort of working method using threads - but it was causing reliability issues when variables were rewritten between threads.  I was pointed towards using ping async and tasks, but I'm getting the following exception:

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.
```

That points specifically to the "await PingAsync(HostList)" and "await Task.WhenAll(tasks)"

Heres the code:

```
            MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            Connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand query = Connection.CreateCommand();
            query.CommandText = "SELECT obj_id AS id,ip FROM objects LIMIT 15";
            MySqlDataReader Nodes = query.ExecuteReader();

            // Record in log that a NEW iteration is starting - for tracking issues with pings
            Library.WriteErrorLog("######################## New Iteration ########################");

            var HostList = new List<HostObject>();

            int i = 1;
            while (Nodes.Read())
            {
                var Host = new HostObject();
                Host.HostName = Nodes["ip"].ToString();
                Host.HostID = Nodes["id"].ToString();
                HostList.Add(Host);
                i++;
            }

            Connection.Close();

            var results = await PingAsync(HostList);
            bool WaitingOnPings = false;
            while (WaitingOnPings == false)
            {
                if (results != null)
                {
                    foreach (PingReply result in results)
                    {
                        Library.WriteErrorLog(result.Status.ToString());
                    }

                    WaitingOnPings = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
```

and :

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync(List<HostObject> HostList)
    {
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        var tasks = HostList.Select(HostName => pingSender.SendPingAsync(HostName.ToString(), 2000));
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return results.ToList();
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ping` was probably not intended to be used for multiple concurrent requests. Try creating a new `Ping` object for each host.

```
private async Task<List<PingReply>> PingAsync(List<HostObject> HostList)
{
    var tasks = HostList.Select(HostName => new Ping().SendPingAsync(HostName.ToString(), 2000));
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I think it's a step in the right direction, but now I'm getting `Error: System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known`  Checking the strings, its a valid ipv4 address.  The same strings that worked when doing this without async.  Example ip from the list: 10.60.138.1.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I got it, had to select the HostObject and use HostOjbect.HostName.  Thank you for the help!